# configure rcsserver and have trouble with boost

Tags: ubuntu, simulation, configure, robocup

I want to configure rcsserver at ubuntu 13.04 with boost V 1.53
I extract rccserver 15-2
I used this at extracted folder from .tar.gz file:

```
$./configure
```

but at last...

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for boostlib >= 1.32.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_system !
```

i dont know what does "Could not link against boost_system !" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use same team name you should change it's name :)